# How to add a Circle() behind a png image in Swift

Tags: swift, image, swiftui

I have a google image stored that have transparent background. Because the blue part of the logo is almost the same as the background (as the 1st image) where is at, I want to add a white circle behind it.

[image: image 1]

To do it, this is what I did:

```
                    ZStack{
                            Circle().frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                               .background(Color.white)
                            Image("Google")
                                .renderingMode(.original)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                                .padding(.all, 3)
                                       
                        }
```

But, what I'm getting is this, as if the center of the image doesn't " recognizes" there's a white circle (its also displaying a square instead of a circle) in front of the blue background :

[image: image 2]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you mean you want a background, that is also a circle, can you provide me the image so i can test it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use clipShape to make it a circle like this:

```
ZStack{
    Circle().frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        .background(Color.white)
        .clipShape(Circle())
    Image("Google")
        .renderingMode(.original)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        .padding(.all, 3)
    
}
```

If you want to get ride of the circle background and keep just it's line, you can use `.stroke()` as shown below:

```
 ZStack{
    Circle()
        .stroke()
        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        .background(Color.white)
        .clipShape(Circle())
    
    Image("Google")
        .renderingMode(.original)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        .padding(.all, 3)
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After reading the answers given, I got an easier way to solve it. I just changed `.background(Color.white)` to `.foregroundcolor(.white)`